# Página PHP ejecuta el Blanco

Tags: php, html

aquí de nuevo peleando y luchando (claro que así se aprende). Tengo una página PHP que me ejecuta en blanco. He revisado mil tutoriales, para poder saber como visualizar el error. Pero no tengo forma de saber donde está mi error. Ya que ni desde la consola me dice nada. Lo extraño es que otras páginas si me las ejecuta o me chiva "errores". Sin embargo esta no hay manera. Ni cambiando el PHP.INI Y todavía no controlo las funciones o "echo" que puedan ayudarme a ver el los errores más personalizados. Son dos archivos, uno es un formulario (que funciona correctamente) y el otro es el código PHP, que solo visualiza la primera línea.

Os dejo el código gracias.

PHP que contiene el formulario:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Libro de Visitas</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="iso-8859-1">
    </head>
    <body>

    <p align="center"><strong>Libro de Visitas</strong></p>

    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

    <?php   

    if (isset($_POST['nombre']) || isset($_POST['texto'])) {

    $libro = new libro("visitas.txt");
    $libro->escribir($_POST['nombre'], $_POST['texto']);

    $libro_ver=new libro(visitas.txt);
    echo $libro_ver->leer();
    }

    ?>

    </table>

    <form action="libro-visitas.php" method="POST">

    <p>Nombre:
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">
    </p>

    <p>Texto:
    <textarea name="texto" id="texto">

    </textarea>
    </p>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="enviar">

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Y este el archivo que contine el PHP a ejecutar el que sale en blanco (libro-visitas.php):

```
<?php 
echo 'La versión actual de PHP es: ' . phpversion();
//Definimos la clase

/**
 * Clase Libro->funcion leer -> funcion escribir
 */
class libro {

    private $tamano;
    private $nombre;
    private $descriptor;
    private $contenido;

    function __construct($nombre)
    {
        $this->nombre=$nombre;
    }

    public function leer() {
        $this->descriptor=fopen($this->nombre,"a+");
        $this->tamano=filesize($this->nombre);

        if ($this->tamano>0) {
            $this->contenido=fread($this->descriptor,$this->tamano);
        }

        fclose($this->descriptor);
        return $this->contenido;
    }

    public function escribir($nombre,$texto) {

        $this->descriptor=fopen($this->nombre,"a+");
        $nombre="<tr><td bgcolor=#CCCCCC>$nombre</td></tr>";

        $texto ="<tr><td bgcolor=#FFFFFF>$texto</td></tr>";

        fputs($this->descriptor,$nombre);
        fputs($this->descriptor,$texto);

        fclose($this->descriptor);
    }


}

?>
```

Gracias Amigos,

Comment: en el archivo donde tienes el formulario, donde estas importando o requiriendo tu archivo libro-visitas.php?

Comment: Hola Alfredo. Muchas gracias por contestarme. A mi la pagina de formulario me ejecuta correctamente. Y cuando envío, me ejecuta la primera linea (echo 'L...). Lo puse a drede para saber si el enlace lo hace correctamente y si que sale. Pero más de ahí, nada. :(

Comment: Estás llamando a la clase libro en la página del formulario, pero no incluyes el archivo, sino que le envías el formulario. La parte donde llamas a libro_ ver debería estar en este archivo destino del formulario para recoger las variables y mostrarte algo. O bien haces un include del archivo y envías el formulario a esta misma página donde lo muestras.

Comment: Es un problema *entendimiento* de cómo funciona. Cuando tú envías un formulario, se ejecuta generalmente el archivo que tienes aquí: `action="libro-visitas.php"` Ese archivo no debería ser la clase `libro`, sino otro archivo que incluya, instancie y use esa clase. O sea, justamente el código que tienes en el mismo archivo del formulario en esta parte: `<?php   if (isset($_POST['nombre']) || isset($_POST['texto'])) {    $libro = new libro("visitas.txt");  ...` ese código debe ser el del archivo `libro-visitas.php` puedes hacer una prueba poniendo simplemente `echo "Hola";` y verás que funciona.

Comment: Hola Amigos, muchísimas gracias por vuestros comentarios me han sido de gran ayuda, para entender mejor que estoy haciendo, y gracias a eso he llegado a la conclusión de que el error está en el primer PHP, que tiene el formulario: $libro_ver=new libro(visitas.txt); Resulta que no lo entrecomillé y claro me la estaba cogiendo como un argumento más lo correcto es $libro_ver=new libro("visitas.txt"); así. No obstante insisto me ha venido de perlas vuestros comentarios, porque gracias a luchar con ello, lo entiendo todo muchísimo mejor. Gracias de verdad.

Comment: Vuelta a probar y efectivamente me faltaba un include (además de ese error), ya ta solucionado :).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes cambiar `libro-visitas.php` por `index.php` (o como llames el php donde esta el html)
y aquí:

```
if (isset($_POST['nombre']) || isset($_POST['texto'])) {

$libro = new libro("visitas.txt");
$libro->escribir($_POST['nombre'], $_POST['texto']);

$libro_ver=new libro(visitas.txt);
echo $libro_ver->leer();
}
```

Agregarle un **`include "libro-visitas.php";`** antes del `if` o de **`$libro = new libro("visitas.txt");`**

Comment: Hola! Ya conseguí ver el error es un error de sintaxis, gracias a vuestros consejos, se filtró y el fallo, y wualá: $libro_ver=new libro("visitas.txt"); ahí estaba el error. Gracias de verdad.